# LESS fails on missing value from a list in Map/List

Tags: css, less

The idea is to add a 'default' value to the list and if one exists, output a class. If the 'default' doesn't exists, the compiler fails. How can this be achieved?

I tried a few variations of Less Guards and couldn't figure out a way to solve the problem.

I also attempted to add a 'default' list for these situations but they aren't merging.

Current Less I'm testing:

```
// Map / List
@borderRadius: {
    //default: .25rem;
    none: 0;
    small: .3rem;
    medium: .5rem;
    large: 1rem;
    round: 9999px;
}

// Extract
.getKeyFromList(@list, @key, @fallback...) {
    .-(length(@list));
    .-(@i) when (@i > 0) {.-((@i - 1))}
    .-(@i) when (@key = extract(extract(@list, @i), 1)) {
        @value: extract(@list, @i);
    }

    .--() {@value: @fallback} .--;
}

// Generate the CSS
& when not (@borderRadius) {
    .getKeyFromList(@borderRadius[default], @borderRadius[default]);

    &radius {
        border-radius: @value;
    }
}
```

EDIT:
Here is my real-world example.
I'm trying to extract the 'responsive' key from each `@@component` to generate responsive modifier classes dynamically
for individual components/variants. I was able to get the :hover and :focus variants to work, but can't figure out a
good way to do it for media queries (responsive modifier classes)

```
@responsiveModifiers: true;
@breakpointOffset: 1;

@screens: {
    small: 768px;
    medium: 960px;
    large: 1440px;
};

@opacity: {
    0: 0;
    25: .25;
    50: .5;
    75: .75;
    100: 1;
}

@borderRadius: {
    none: 0;
    small: .3rem;
    medium: .5rem;
    large: 1rem;
    round: 9999px;
}

@components: {
    @opacity: {
        enabled: false;
        responsive: false;
        hover: true;
        focus: false;
    }
    @borderRadius: {
        enabled: true;
        responsive: false;
        hover: true;
        focus: false;
    }
}

.config() {

    // Create generators here
    & when (@components[@opacity][enabled]) {
        @component: opacity;
        .generate(opacity, opacity, @opacity);
    }

    & when (@components[@borderRadius][enabled]) {
        @component: opacity;
        .generate(radius, border-radius, @borderRadius);
    }

}

// Call the mixin for default, non media-query classes
// and prefix it with a period (.)
.groundwork-utility-classes() {
    @period: .;
    @{period} {
        .config();
    }
}

// Dynamically generate CSS responsive modifiers, per breakpoint,
// via the @screens list array
.groundwork-media-queries() when (@responsiveModifiers = true) {
    each(@screens, {
        @media screen and (min-width: (@value + @breakpointOffset)) {
            .@{key}&\: {
                .config();
            }
        }
    })
}

// Main mixin to generate all CSS utility classes
.generate(@className; @property; @list) {

    // Generate CSS classes from a @list array
    // e.g `.generate(p, padding, @padding);`
    each(@list, {
        & when not (@key > 0) {
            &@{className} {
                @{property}: @value;
            }
            &hover\:@{className}:hover when (@components[@@component][hover] = true) {
                @{property}: @value;
            }
            &focus\:@{className}:focus when (@components[@@component][focus] = true) {
                @{property}: @value;
            }
        }
    });
}

// Render non media-query classes together
.groundwork-utility-classes();

// Group and render media queries together,
.groundwork-media-queries();
```

Comment: You seem to have a lot of problems with *basic* Less concepts (variables, mixins and their parameters) you have to train a bit before entering a complex snippets like this. E.g. `& when not (@borderRadius)` makes zero sense (what it is supposed to do?). `.getKeyFromList(@borderRadius[default], @borderRadius[default]);` -> zero sense as well. You also randomly mixed two orthiogonal patterns from different sources (in short `@borderRadius` is not a *list* `.getKeyFromList` would work with). E.g. in summary this does not look like there were any efforts on your side (just a random copy-paste).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, although it's very unhelpful. I actually have a lot experience with Less, I've just never done anything like this before. Yes, `.getKeyFromList` was  copy and paste, I think from something you've originally posted. But the Guard was just an experiment that I left in the snippet. I guess for this question, I should've left it out. Last thing, if you paste the snippet into Lesstester, you'll see `.getKeyFromList(@borderRadius[default], @borderRadius[default]);` gets the default from the list.

Comment: Also, why not offer a useful answer, so I can actually progress and learn more, rather than putting up a brick wall basically? Your answer doesn't help me solve the problem at all. Maybe I asked the question badly, but you can also state that if it's the case.

Comment: *why not offer a useful answer, so I can actually progress and learn more* - you won't progress in swimming by jumping right into Niagara or watching others do that. Start with minimalistic snippets - e.g. try to do basic use of `when` conditions and what happens if try to use use non-existent `@borderRadius[default]` there (hint: you don't need any `.getKeyFromList` at all. And just reading the documentation for `when` should be more than enough to write that one line of the code that will do the trick).

Comment: I'm sorry, but I your comment is very condescending and arrogant. Why do you assume I haven't tried a bunch of stuff (I have, lots of thing). BTW, the docs don't mention at all how to get a specific key from a MAP list, so that's where the experimentation started. Last thing to add: your stance is a reason why some people (me for one) find it a really difficult to post questions on SO, because you're required to ask questions in a certain and post code snippets (which I did).

Comment: *the docs don't mention at all how to get a specific key from a MAP list* - [they do](http://lesscss.org/features/#maps-feature). And my stance is just the usual defense from turning the SO into "code writing service".

Comment: You're right, thank you. The problem is I didn't post a real-world example of what I'm trying to achieve, but rather just a snippet/rough idea. I've edited (added to) my question accordingly.
P.S. Do you really feel that SO is turning into "code writing service"? Is that a new stance of yours (your answers generally seem very detailed)?